# how to set time first and then date in bootstrap datetime picker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set bootstrap date-time picker, such that when we set date-time it should prompt to set time first and then prompt to display date. How to achieve this?

```
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' id="datetime" name="eventdate" placeholder="select date and time" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div><br/>

     $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
     });
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far..

Comment: share your code here for more help.

Comment: I haven't tried anything